# How to alternate between multimedia keys and actual keys in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: keyboard, multimedia

My Inspiron 5547 has its multimedia keys mapped on top of F1 to F12. SO, I can't use these keys normally.

Is there a way to alternate between multimedia function and normal function in the same spirit of an AltGr+key? But, I want the normal F1-F12 to be the default.

My keyboard is Native Brazilian.

Comment: Press `Fn`+`F#`. You can lock and unlock `Fn`-functionality of the `F#`keys by pressing `Fn`+`Esc`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify the order. I want the default to be the normal F1-F12 keys.

Comment: You have to check if you can set a default in your BIOS. In doubt take a look in the manual for your hardware. The `Fn`-key is not handled by any OS, it is a keyboard-internal thing.